# Doctrine Query Builder Select Count with Case

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following sql-statement that I want to transform into doctrine query builder. The goal is to count how many ratings exist with rating value 1 and with rating value 2.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN rating.rating = 1 THEN rating.rating END) as rat1, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN rating.rating = 2 THEN rating.rating END) as rat2 
FROM rating
```

This sql statement is working fine - but when I try to transform it into a Doctrine statement, it does not anymore. When nothing should get counted (because no ratings for this value exist), it returns me a "1" instead of a 0. How can I tell doctrine to simply return a zero when there is nothing to count?
I tried it by removing the "ELSE 0" , but then I get an error that this part is required..

```
return $qb
        ->addSelect('COUNT(CASE WHEN r.rating = 1 THEN r.rating ELSE 0 END) as rat_1')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(CASE WHEN r.rating = 2 THEN r.rating ELSE 0 END) as rat_2')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Regards,

> "sum" is not required - example:
>   votings 2,2,2,2,2 should return 5 , because the rating with value 2 got voted 5 times.

Comment: use `sum` instead of `count` to get what you need.

Comment: hey, I don't want to sum up the values 1+1+1+1, or 2+2+2+2+, I want to count how often a value got rated, e.g. 2+2+2+2 = 4 (times for rating with value 2). Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As vkp mentioned, you can use `SUM` but instead of summing the rating, sum either a 1 or a 0 to simulate a `COUNT`

```
SUM(CASE WHEN r.rating = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. So this is the workaround, because I cannot use a Count here directly ? Thank you.

Comment: Your edit comment is false - when using dql it throws "Error: Unexpected 'NULL'". The SUM - suggestion is working fine.

Comment: Sum does not help in case you need to count distinct values in one column depending on the values in another column. For that case see my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

To count distinct id's in one column depending on the value in another column  the answer from Fuzzy Tree does not work in this case.

To count only the distinct values you should give null as a parameter and set it to null like:

```
->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN r.rating = 1 THEN rating.rating ELSE :nada END)) as rat_1')
->setParameter(':nada', null)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was trying to set null in the case statement and kept getting an error. Setting it as a parameter works perfectly.